# which table should I query for date & time in zabbix?

Tags: time, zabbix, query, date

i need to query date and time in zabbix server. which table exactly stores these 2 parameters?

Actually there is a table named history and there are two fields in that table named "clock" and "ns", but their formats is too odd and i cannot extract date/time from them. (also i dont know what "ns" means)

for i.e the formats are ---> "clock": "1351090996" and "ns": "563157632"

thanks,

Comment: what do you mean with "i need to query date and time in zabbix server" ? date and time of what ?

Comment: I write a program in c# and I use some sql queries in my codes in order to fetch some data from zabbix DB. In zabbix front-end u can select which date/time to give u a graph. so I want to do same things in my c# code not a front-end but i dont know which table should i select from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to retrieve historical data. You should query history/history_uint/history_str/history_text/history_log tables depending on the data type item receives.

- `clock` is [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
- `ns` is nanoseconds in that second. You can probably ignore it.

Comment: same as my previous post, u solve my problem. thanks ;) so I should convert unix timestamp in my c# code.